# How to select data by using range of dates in MySql query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a problem related to MySQL query, I use WAMPServer.
I have data in database which have range of dates but when I select data for example

```
select * from CHD WHERE  addtime>='2018-06-15' and addtime<='2018-06-21';
```

It displays data from '2018-06-15' to '2018-06-20', data of 2018-06-21 are not displayed even if I do

```
select * from CHD where addtime='2018-06-21';
```

is not working

Please anyone can help me

Comment: what is addtime's type?  is it a date?  datetime?  varchar?

Comment: If its a DATETIME column try `WHERE  addtime>='2018-06-15' and addtime<='2018-06-21 23:59:59';` as if you just use `2018-06-21` it will assume `2018-06-21 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that your column is of type datetime.

The shorthand version of your date in the filter clause is assumed to be at midnight of the date.  Your values that you are attempting to retrieve have times after midnight of that date.  You either need to define a timestamp along with the date, or you need to filter by the day after for less than equal to or the day before for greater than equal